# Converting a complex nested JSON to CSV or Excel using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a nested JSON which I need to convert to a CSV. I have initially worked on simple JSON and able to convert it. But this has some complex nested objects for which I'm facing difficulties. Below is the JSON:

```
{
    "next": "https://api.pro.live/api/v1.0/publisher/pages?api_key=ujwq8aW7MOZ6y40nXhrrqW0OxnIvNJnFzpWOcJaSWHc&format=json&page_number=2",
    "next_page": 2,
    "previous": null,
    "previous_page": null,
    "count": 8888,
    "data": [{
        "id": "294225",
        "publisher_id": "here",
        "name": "Company Page",
        "publisher_page_id": "",
        "publisher_page_url": "",
        "state": "active",
        "state_description": "",
        "crawled_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "location": {
            "id": "163238",
            "name": "Buffard Fabrice",
            "address": {
                "address_line1": "Allée de l'Abron",
                "address_line2": "",
                "house_number": "5",
                "city": "Gennetines",
                "zip_code": "03400",
                "sublocality": "",
                "state": "",
                "country": "FR",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 46.6376484,
                    "longitude": 3.4076838
                }
            },
            "phones": [{
                "type": "main",
                "number": "0470421022",
                "country_code": ""
            }, {
                "type": "mobile",
                "number": "0662241230",
                "country_code": ""
            }],
            "urls": [{
                "type": "website",
                "url": "http://www.fabrice-buffard.fr",
                "description": "",
                "display_url": ""
            }],
            "emails": [{
                "email": "photo@fabrice-buffard.fr",
                "type": "contact",
                "description": ""
            }],
            "closed": false,
            "opening_hours": {
                "periods": [{
                    "open_day": "MONDAY",
                    "open_time": "14:00",
                    "close_day": "MONDAY",
                    "close_time": "19:00"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "TUESDAY",
                    "open_time": "10:00",
                    "close_day": "TUESDAY",
                    "close_time": "12:30"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "TUESDAY",
                    "open_time": "14:00",
                    "close_day": "TUESDAY",
                    "close_time": "19:00"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "open_time": "10:00",
                    "close_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "close_time": "12:30"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "open_time": "14:00",
                    "close_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "close_time": "19:00"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "open_time": "10:00",
                    "close_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "close_time": "12:30"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "open_time": "14:00",
                    "close_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "close_time": "19:00"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "FRIDAY",
                    "open_time": "10:00",
                    "close_day": "FRIDAY",
                    "close_time": "12:30"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "FRIDAY",
                    "open_time": "14:00",
                    "close_day": "FRIDAY",
                    "close_time": "19:00"
                }, {
                    "open_day": "SATURDAY",
                    "open_time": "10:00",
                    "close_day": "SATURDAY",
                    "close_time": "12:30"
                }]
            },
            "specific_opening_hours": [],
            "publisher_categories": [{
                "name": "Photographer",
                "id": "gcid:photographer"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I was able to extract few of the objects from the above json, but when it comes to complex nested structure, it becomes difficult. I need help to develop a  I  generic converter so that if one structure misses a field, then it should not throw me an error.

Below is a part of my code where I individually extract each object but doesn't work when one structure misses a field,

```
x["data"][numbers]["id"],
                x["data"][numbers]["publisher_id"],
                x["data"][numbers]["name"],
                x["data"][numbers]["publisher_page_id"],
                x["data"][numbers]["publisher_page_url"],
                x["data"][numbers]["state"],
                x["data"][numbers]["state_description"],
                x["data"][numbers]["crawled_at"],
                x["data"][numbers]["updated_at"]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
x["data"][numbers].get("id"),
x["data"][numbers].get("publisher_id"),
...
```

.get(...) will return None in case the key is not present in the dict. If you want to return a different default, use .get(key, default)